# Qual é a relação entre as canções "Lemon Tree" e "Meu Limão, Meu Limoeiro"

Tags: letras-de-músicas

Quando eu era criança, meus pais tocavam "[Lemon Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemon_Tree_(Will_Holt_song))", de William Holt, uma música sobre como o amor traz doçura e dor, como um limoeiro. Meu entendimento é que Holt se baseou em "[Meu Limão, Meu Limoeiro](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meu_Lim%C3%A3o,_Meu_Limoeiro)", uma canção folclórica brasileira, mas pela minha leitura, a única relação entre os dois é que falam de limões e limoeiros. Meu português ainda não é muito bom, então acho que posso ter perdido algum detalhe significativo em "Meu Limão, Meu Limoeiro".

"Meu Limão, Meu Limoeiro" é também sobre a doçura e a amargura do amor?

Comment: How could they possibly be linked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta é a letra de [**"Meu Limão, Meu limoeiro"**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vgCXJAuygpk) uma canção muito antiga, parte do cancioneiro infantil da primeira metade do século passado.

> Meu limão, meu limoeiro.
> Meu pé de jacarandá
> Uma vez, esquindô lelê
> Outra vez, esquindô lalá

Sim, a letra original parece ser só isso, repetida várias vezes. Uma letra pueril, que praticamente nada diz.

[**Wikipedia**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meu_Lim%C3%A3o,_Meu_Limoeiro), contudo, diz o seguinte a respeito da música:

> Meu limão, meu limoeiro é uma composição de José Carlos Burle e foi escrita nos anos 30, primeiramente gravada em 1937 por Silvio Caldas e Gidinho e, ainda no mesmo ano, por Jorge Fernandes. Foi gravada ainda por intérpretes como Inezita Barroso, Eduardo Araújo e Wilson Simonal, com este último elevando a composição a sucesso nacional no ano de 1966. A canção deu origem à Lemon Tree de Will Holt (1960)[1]

> [**1**](http://web.archive.org/web/20190723220340if_/https://jc.ne10.uol.com.br/blogs/toques/2015/06/05/will-holt-19292015-autor-americano-de-meu-limao-meu-limoeiro/).   Teles, José (5 de junho de 2015). «Will Holt (1929/2015), "autor" americano de Meu limão, meu limoeiro

Já o site da [Cover Records](http://1001covers.blogspot.com/2018/04/cover-records-origem-da-cancao-meu.html#comment-form) atribui a canção a outrem.

> - **ao se aprofundar nas pesquisas, não é possível afirmar quando teria sido composta e nem quem seriam os verdadeiros autores de Meu  Limão, Meu Limoeiro.** Alguns pesquisadores acreditam que sua origem tenha **raízes no folclore baiano**, tendo sido recolhida pela primeira vez na década de 1910 pela pianista **Carolina Cardoso de Menezes** e **Francisco Pereira**.

De qualquer forma, a versão de José Carlos Burle, da década de 30, tinha a letra bem mais longa, conforme cita o site da [**Cover Records**](http://1001covers.blogspot.com/2018/04/cover-records-origem-da-cancao-meu.html#comment-form), e que transcrevo abaixo. Suponho que o OP tenha se referido a essa versão da canção.

> A verdade é que a música tem origem no folclore nordestino. A parte que compete a Jose Carlos Burle é o trecho:

> "Morena, minha morena
> Corpo de linha torcida
> Queira deus você não seja
> Perdição da minha vida"

> "Quem tem amores não dorme
> Nem de noite, nem de dia
> Dá tantas voltas na cama
> Como peixe n´água fria"

> "A folhinha do alecrim
> Cheira mais quando pisada
> Há muita gente que é assim,
> Quer mais bem se desprezada"

> Mas o trecho mais conhecido é verdadeiramente de domínio público.

> A versão de Burle é mais conhecida, mas não é a mais antiga. A mais antiga é de Carolina Cardoso de Menezes e Francisco Pereira, datada década de 1910.

Embora [**José Teles**](http://web.archive.org/web/20190723220340if_/https://jc.ne10.uol.com.br/blogs/toques/2015/06/05/will-holt-19292015-autor-americano-de-meu-limao-meu-limoeiro/) afirme que a canção brasileira serviu de inspiração para Will Holt compor "Lemon Tree" em 1950, isso pode até ser verdade, mas a letra das duas músicas nada têm em comum, exceto falarem de um limoeiro.

A letra de [**"Lemon Tree**"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eceRvPx3wrs), composta por Holt em 1950, e que tornou-se um sucesso com a gravação de  Peter, Paul and Mary em 1963, conta uma história de amor e ruptura, testemunhada por um limoeiro. É uma canção muito bonita (opinião pessoal).  mas, da mesma forma que a letra, a melodia também é completamente diferente do nosso "meu limão, meu limoeiro.

Para complicar as coisas, existe uma terceira música também chamada [**"Lemon Tree"**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l2UiY2wivTs) que em nada se parece com a outra lemon tree ou com a canção brasileira.

Crédito a @LoremIpsum, que conseguiu recuperar o link da ref. 1.

Comment: Obrigado. Achei que isso pudesse ser verdade.